# Play! framework - public file not found

Tags: java, web, playframework-2.0

I added a file as part of the public assets of the project:
`public/style/style.css`

this is the route for public assets in `routes` file:
`# Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
GET     /assets/*file controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)`

this is the link to the style.css file:
`http://localhost:9000/assets/style/style.css`

but, somehow this link is broken. why is that?
other files (for example js libraries) are ok.

Comment: Did you ever figure out why this was causing you problems? I'm working with play and I'm running into the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Two things to check, should help you:

- make sure that `public/style/style.css` is not empty.
- make sure that you haven't similar file path available for LESS ie.: `app/assets/style` or `app/assets/style/style.css`

Although it's just guessing I sometimes have similar problem which most often is caused by one of the above points.