# Playframework not serving assets located in Public folder

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.2

I wrote some views for an application and I am now trying to integrate them with Play.

This is the relevant route from my routes file.

```
GET     /assets/*file                  controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

All of my css files are in public/stylesheets. All of my javascript files are in public/javascripts

This is how I'm trying to call the file from my view.

```
    <script type='text/javascript' src='@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/modernizer.js")'>     </script>
```

This is what I see when I look at the rendered html on the page.

```
    <script type='text/javascript' src='/assets/javascripts/modernizer.js'></script>
```

It looks like it has the correct path but when I try to click on the file, there is nothing there.

I've made sure that I don't have any similar files in my assets folder as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12697647/play-framework-public-file-not-found) thread. I've also made sure that the file is not empty.

Why aren't the files in my public folder being served?

Comment: What is the HTTP response code?

Comment: @JamesWard How do I check that? I've read in the documentation where you can check that with integration tests. Is that what you're talking about?

Comment: Use the Chrome inspector, Firebug, curl, etc to see what the response code is.